# How to separate BCS list and form in two site pages?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript, sharepoint-server, asp.net

I am using a BCS and External Content Types in SharePoint to Update SQL Tables; however, I would like to have this two parts separated in different pages.

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you mean by "two parts"? BCS is a general name for the SharePoint technology that allows for interaction between SP and outside data, not something that would appear on a specific page. ECT's describe an individual "entity" (in practice, usually a table or view.)

Comment: Separating the form and the table view. I want to create a page with only the form, and create a second page with a table view only.

Comment: Okay, just throwing out ideas you could try - for the table view, there are BCS-specific web parts (similar to the normal list view web parts, but not as feature-rich). They could be used to display data from the table

Comment: For the form, if you're comfortable working with SharePoint Designer, you could try opening up the existing add item form and find the web part that handles interaction with the list, and then try creating the same type of web part on another page. -- If you're a developer, you could experiment with this approach and see if it's possible (never tried it myself though.)

Comment: Thank you for the idea. I got the same idea yesterday, so I experiment more today.